# Citreon c4 grand picasso clutch burnt out semi auto

Tags: clutch, citroen

Can anyone help...  I got a car in Jan then early Feb it broke down and RAC said clutch had gone... The garage I got it from took car back for inspection to decide if I can get refund... Just heard no refund because apparently I caused the problem.  They say I was driving it for long periods in manual 1st gear that caused clutch to burn out.  I only have automatic licence and I'm not stupid enough to do that. 
Am I right in thinking there must have been an issue before it was sold?

I was driving the car for 2 and half weeks

Comment: While it would be possible to burn the clutch out in that time, it's very unlikely. I'd say there was almost certainly already an issue. I'd get an independent professional to give a second opinion

Comment: I also have a Citroen Grand Picasso C4 (2017). I think the issue is that annoying gear stick placement (near the wheel) where it is very hard to determine what gear you at. The manual state is right before the Drive and it is very hard to determine which is which. Many times it happens that you switch form parking to manual and only later realize that. Maybe you have no issue with it, but perhaps your wife or some one else driving the car?